# how to detect firewall with scapy

Tags: firewall, scapy

I open a port 4000 on  computer A and send a packet from another remote computer B
but A didn't get the packet, I think maybe the enterprise firewall filtered the packet
how can I detect this?
are there any traceroute functions in scapy or other tools that can detect this?
thanks!

Answer (score 1):

what was the function that you used in scapy and how did you open a port?
detection of the firewall depends to type of the firewall and term of network.

traceroute in scapy ==> 
traceroute("www.google.com", maxttl=10)

Answer (score 0):

first probe the port using nmap through different tcp scan types (ex:-sS/-sT) to check if it's open or not, if it works then craft a packet similar to this one:

"ans,unans=sr(IP(dst="rhost here"/TCP(flags="S",sport=RandShort(), dport=4000, verbose=0, timeout=2"
then -> ans.show()

if you get SA(SYN/ACK) response then port is open and filtering is disabling on this port
otherwise it's closed when you get RA(RST/ACK) or filtered if no response(SYN flag set)